# Sql Role Provider

Tags: sql, asp.net, role

I am new to asp.net and I am trying to implement my role provider, actually sql role provider. In my Role Provider I added:

```css
 public void AddUsersToRole(string[] usernames, string[] rolenames)
        {
            SqlConnection conn =
                 new SqlConnection(
                     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users " +
                                               " (Username, Role) " +
                                               " Values(?, ?)", conn);
            SqlParameter Username = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            SqlParameter Role = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Role", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);


            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                foreach (string username in usernames)
                {
                    foreach (string rolename in rolenames)
                    {
                        Username.Value = username;
                        Role.Value = rolename;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

But when I put in my login page the following:

```
                    Roles.AddUsersToRole(TextBoxUsername.Text, DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.Value);
```

And when I build it I got an error.

Please help, tnx in advance.

Comment: what error did you got ? can you show that error and did you tried debugging your code that why are you getting that error

Comment: Why not make use of asp.net membership provider?

Comment: the errors are: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUsersToRole(string[],string) has some invalid arguments"; and "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method expecting `string[]` but you are providing `string`.

```
Roles.AddUsersToRole(TextBoxUsername.Text, DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.Value);

public void AddUsersToRole(string[] usernames, string[] rolenames)
```

solution:

```
Roles.AddUsersToRole(new string[] { TextBoxUsername.Text }, new string[] { DropDownListRole.SelectedItem.Value });
```

Comment: I have again problem with errors, now I got error on login page: "Error The method or operation is not implemented". I suppose smth went wrong with AddUsersToRole method. Do you have any idea what could be a problem?

Comment: you should create new question with error and related codes. It doesn't seem these codes causing your problem.